# Create Custom culture in sitecore 10.3 azure hosted app

Tags: azure, multilingual, paas, sitecore-managed-cloud

We have a requirement to create certain custom cultures (for e.g. en-JP) that are by default not registered in .Net.

Has anyone tried registering new custom culture in azure web app service?

Comment: Hi Anna, This post says its not possible to register culture in azure app service. Since its an old post i am wondering if the capability is introduced now in azure.

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: With 10.3 I don't think you need to anymore. You can just add thr custom language. I know you can in XM Cloud

Comment: I don't have a 10.3 setup to test it now, but as Richared mentioned, it is implemented for xmcloud, and with a high possibility you will have it for 10.3:
https://www.ashournia.com/new-xmcloud-language-localizations/

Comment: @GhodratAshournia  I don't see the custom culture section in the language item of 10.3 vanilla instance

Comment: If that is the case, you can create a feature request. you can open a support ticket and ask, if they can integrate the xmCloud integration to the XP:

https://developers.sitecore.com/changelog/xm-cloud/custom-language-support

It will be a useful feature. Basically it will remove the dependency on the .net framework cultures.

Comment: Thanks @GhodratAshournia I will raise the feature request